# What is this? m or n

Tags: preposition, spelling

Ok, I am asking about this website:

https://www.dw.com/de/top-thema-mit-vokabeln-archiv-2020/a-51533674

There the articles start with phrases like these:

- Thema vo**m** Freitag, 10. Januar 2020
- Thema vo**n** Freitag, 31. Januar 2020
- Thema vo**n** Freitag, 07. Februar 2020
- Thema vo**m** Freitag, 14. Februar 2020
- Thema vo**n** Freitag, 06.03.2020
- Thema vo**m** Freitag, 13. März 2020

Vo**n** Freitag? Vo**m** Freitag? Does it matter? Why did this happen? I think it's correct to say "am Freitag" with m. So is vom correct? Somewhat related, have people been saying "an Heiligabend"? Or "am Heiligabend"? I only heard "an" with n, from my friend.

I would appreciate help.

Comment: Es heißt eigentlich "am Heiligabend", aber seit 2019 setzt sich immer mehr dieses unsäglich nervige "an Weihnachten" & Co. durch, was mir tierisch auf die Nerven geht, und deswegen kann man auch sagen "an Heiligabend".

Comment: Ergänzung zum Kommentar von @äüö: In Österreich heißt es nicht *»am Heiligabend«* sondern *»am Heiligen Abend«* denn der halbe Feiertag, der am 24. Dezember im Kalender steht, heißt in Österreich nicht *»Heiligabend«* sondern *»Heiliger Abend«.* Die darauffolgenden Feiertage heißen: 25.12. = *»Christtag«* und 26.12. = *»[Stefanitag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefanitag)«* wobei die Betonung auf dem langen A in *Stefan* liegt: Stef**aa**nitag. In österreichischen Kalendern kommt das Wort *Weihnacht* nicht vor. Siehe auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feiertage_in_Österreich

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Mal wieder eine Gemeinsamkeit mit Schwäbisch.

Answer (score 1):

Those dates are all in the dative case, but there is a degree of flexibility possible regarding the preposition *von / vom < von dem/diesem* or *an / am < an dem/diesem*, because the determiner *dem* can be forbidden, allowed or mandatory.

- *vo**n** heute / (vor)gestern / (über)morgen* – relative dates (‘today’, ‘yesterday’, ‘tomorrow’) can never be preceded by *vom* and neither by *von dem*
- *von/vom Montag / Dienstag / Mittwoch / Donnerstag / Freitag / Samstag / Sonnabend / Sonntag* – weekdays can be preceded by either *von* or *vom*, the latter necessarily implying the most recent one. This also applies to related feasts and holidays like *Gründonnerstag, Karfreitag, Ostersonntag, Pfingstmontag, Veilchendienstag, Aschermittwoch* and *Heiligabend*.
- *vo**m** `n`-ten [`m`-ten / Januar/Jänner / Februar/Feber / März / Mai / Juni/Juno / Juli/Julei / August / September / Oktober / November / Dezember / des/dieses/diesen/letzten Monats]* – calendar dates with implied, ordinal, named or relative month and possibly year require *vom*, but *von dem* would sound stilted, strange or plain wrong.
- *von/vom <weekday>, dem/den <calendar date>* – in a combination of weekday and calendar date, one would usually combine either *von* with *dem* or *vom* with *den*, but *von … den* and *vom … dem* also do not sound wrong. One can even omit *den/dem* and the date can then be an apposition in the nominative case with *`n`-ter* instead of a dative attribute with *`n`-ten* (never *`n`-tem*).

Comment: Thank you! Interesting that von dem sounds bad. In English, I think "from the 10th of January" works. And "from 10th of January" sounds bad. I don't understand the last point.

Comment: the last point considers the case *Friday the third* which differs in various constelations as it may be paired variously with prepositions. I often see advertisements with a date, no preposition, "Freitag, dem 13. Aug." where I would say "den", while the Movie of the same name uses nominative "der" (because it's not an appointment but well a title). It needlessly complicates the answer, requiring additional consideration, which can be found under other questions, I'm sure.

Comment: @vectory I don't think it needlessly complicates the answer, I just don't understand it. If this answer already exists at another question, I'm sorry. I can understand use of der, also den. I understand "von Freitag, dem _," but I don't understand "vom Freitag, den _." I guess it's like "am Freitag, den _." I'm not sure.

Comment: For me, "vom Freitag, den ..." and "am Freitag, den ...", although often used, sound so wrong that it hurts, because the grammatical cases mismatch. I'm definitely not the "one"  who would combine "vom with den".

Comment: @Armali How often? Is there a difference between using von and vom, first of all, and if not den, what then? Vom Freitag, dem? Von Freitag, dem? Or?

Comment: _How often?_ Far too often, in my opinion. ;-) Why do you ask? I don't support the view of some people that if a grammatical crime is made commonly enough, it will become legal; but I have to mention that [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/datum) says: "Bei Datumsangaben mit _am_ kann der Kalendertag im Dativ oder im Akkusativ stehen."

Comment: _Is there a difference between using von and vom_? The difference is just the omission of the definite article "dem" in the first variant ("vom" = "von dem"); but that doesn't change the dative case - therefore, I consider both "vom Freitag, dem" and "von Freitag, dem" well-formed.

Comment: @Armali I didn't know if maybe it was something you hear frequently, or only so often. Also, I am asking because I am learning German. Thanks for responding. I'm still confused.